# How to Lock and Enable control of forms on form load event by Tempvars tag using vba access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with various controls (textBox, Combobox, checkBox) with all have different character/string tags (Not Numbers)

I have a another form where a combobox value set as Tempvars!addAltTag and by a button click on that form, this form opens with Tempvars!addAltTag property.

I tried following code but have runtime error code "438"

```
    For Each Ctl In Me.Controls

    If Ctl.Tag = TempVars!addAltTag Then
            Ctl.Locked = False
    Else
            Ctl.Locked = True
    End If

Next Ctl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 438 = "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Therefore I would say you are trying to Lock a control that is not data bound (e.g. trying to lock a Label control for example)

```
Dim intControlType as integer

For Each Ctl In Me.Controls

    intControlType = Ctl.ControlType

    If (intControlType = acCheckBox) Or (intControlType = acComboBox) Or (intControlType = acTextBox) Then

            If Ctl.Tag = TempVars!addAltTag Then
                Ctl.Locked = False
            Else
                Ctl.Locked = True
            End If

    End If

Next Ctl
```

see this page for reference
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa224135(v=office.11).aspx